# p:dataTable not updated by PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update

Tags: jsf, primefaces, listener

I am starting developpment with JSF and PrimeFace datatable. I have prepared the following xhtml page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

        <h:head>
        <title>Find Capital of Countries</title>
        </h:head> 
        <h:body> 
            <h:form id="FrmTest">

                        <p:dataTable id="ListSites"  value="#{testing.SiteSearch()}" var="lst" editable="true">

                        <f:facet name="header">
                            List of Sites
                        </f:facet>

                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                Site Code
                            </f:facet>
                            #{lst.stCode}
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Site Description">
                            <h:outputText value="#{lst.stDescription}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column  headerText="is Active">
                            <div style="text-align: center;">
                                <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{lst.stActive}"  />
                            </div>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                Site Active
                            </f:facet>
                            <div style="text-align: center;">
                                <h:outputText value= "#{lst.stActive}" />
                            </div>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                Modified By
                            </f:facet>
                             #{lst.modifiedBy}
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                Modification Date
                            </f:facet>
                            #{lst.modifiedDate}
                        </p:column>                 

                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                Has Error
                            </f:facet>
                            #{lst.hasError}
                        </p:column>     

                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                Error Description
                            </f:facet>
                            #{lst.errorDescription}
                        </p:column>     

                        <p:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                Row State
                            </f:facet>
                            #{lst.rowState}
                        </p:column>     


                    </p:dataTable>



                <h:outputLabel value="Enter Country Name:"/>
                <h:inputText id="country" binding="#{testing.country}"
                valueChangeListener="#{testing.findCapitalListener}"
                immediate="true"
                onchange="document.getElementById('findcapital').click();" />
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <h:outputLabel value="Capital is: " />
                <h:inputText id="capital" binding="#{testing.capital}" immediate="true"/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <h:commandButton  value="Submit" partialSubmit="true" />
                <div style="visibility: hidden" >
                    <h:commandButton id="findcapital" value="findcapital" partialSubmit="true"  immediate="true" />
                </div>

            </h:form>    
        </h:body> 
    </html>
```

I want entry made in text box named country to update datatable named ListSites. The associated listener is called (system.out.println made) but the primeface update is not made. Here is the listener:

````
   ```
        public void findCapitalListener(ValueChangeEvent cdl) {
        String country = cdl.getNewValue().toString();
        System.out.println("Country is : " + country);
        StringBuilder capitalCountry = new StringBuilder();
        findCapital(country, capitalCountry);
        capital.setValue(capitalCountry.toString());    
        siteDto = listSiteDto.get(0);
        siteDto.setStDescription(capitalCountry.toString());
        listSiteDto.set(0, siteDto);
        PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update("FrmTest:ListSites");
        //System.out.println("Capital is : " + capital.getValue());
        //System.out.println("New DTO Description : " + siteDto.getStDescription());
        System.out.println("New list Description : " + listSiteDto.get(0).getStDescription());
        }
    ```
````

Comment: Hi, learn about [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

The problem was due to the fact that the function populating the datatable (SiteSearch())  was retrieving data from the database. At that stage I wanted to refresh the page display before updating the database. I replaced the function by the list getter, things are working properly now.